# How do I iterate in reverse with *ngFor directive?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, ngfor

In angular, I am trying to query Firebase and i would like when the objects come back, the content is iterated through, in reverse.

In TS I got this

```
 this.items = db.list('/items', ref => ref.limitToLast(10)).valueChanges();
```

I tried using reverse() on there, but, i get an errors saying "Reverse does not exist on type Observerable"

In the HTML i have this

```
*ngFor="let item of items | async | slice:0:100"
```

How can i get this done ?

Comment: `*ngFor="let item of items.slice().reverse()"` Try this.

Comment: That does not work. Seems to be the most common solution and the least likely to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use RxJS operator [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) with pipe to transform the final emitted values:

```
this.items = db.list('/items', ref => ref.limitToLast(10)).valueChanges().pipe(map(values => values.reverse());
```

Answer (score 4):

`valueChanges()` returns an Observable that wraps the underlying data array. In order to reverse the underlying data array you may pipe the Observable through the `map` RxJS operator and return the reversed array.

```js
this.items = db.list('/items', ref => ref.limitToLast(10)).valueChanges()
                     .pipe(
                     map(values => values.reverse())
                     );
```